# DLL Deployment in GAC -ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, deployment

How to set up the Windows installer to launch some DLL into GAC when it is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install some Assemblies in GAC add the special folder "Global Assembly Cache" and put there your assemblies.

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;324168&x=9&y=14